# Random variable for variance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Given a binomial distributed measure $P_\theta$, with parameter $\theta\in (0,1)$ on $\Omega:=\{0,1,\ldots, n\}$. I want to find a random variable

$$R: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad R(x):=?$$

such that

$$E_\theta[R]=\theta(1-\theta).$$

So my first clue was some kind of using the idea that

$$Var_\theta[x]=E_\theta[x^2]-E_\theta[x]^2=n\theta(1-\theta).$$

So I would like to use something like

$$R(x):=\frac{1}{n}(x^2-x)$$

but this only gives

$$E_\theta[R]=\frac{1}{n}(E_\theta[x^2]-E_\theta[x]),$$

such that I am missing the square.

Any hints for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Of course $R$ shall be independent of $\theta$. So you cannot just take

$$R(x):=\frac{1-\theta}{n}x$$

for each $\theta$ or something similiar depending on $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually very close.

The requested item is something which expectation is $\theta(1 - \theta) = \theta - \theta^2$. One option is to find an estimator that is unbiased. Without further requirements, the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) suffices.

Since it is know $E_{\theta}[x] = n\theta$ such that $G(x) \equiv \frac{x}n$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$, as in $E_{\theta}[G] = \theta$ , we can try the simple-minded
$$\theta - \theta^2 \mapsto G - G^2 \qquad \implies \text{ansatz:} \quad R(x) \propto A(x) := \frac{x}n - \left( \frac{x}n \right)^2$$ 
Now let's examine the expectation of $A(x)$.
\begin{align}
E_{\theta}[ A ] &= E_{\theta}\left[ \frac{x}n - \left( \frac{x}n \right)^2 \right] \\
&= \frac1n E_{\theta}[x] - \frac1{ n^2} E_{\theta}[x^2] \\
&= \frac1n \cdot n \theta - \frac1{ n^2} \left( Var_{\theta}[x] + E_{\theta}[x]^2 \right) \\
&= \theta - \frac1{ n^2} \left( n\theta(1-\theta) + n^2\theta^2 \right) \\
&= \theta - \frac1{ n^2} \left( n\theta + n(n-1)\theta^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{n-1}n \left( \theta  - \theta^2\right)
\end{align}
That is, $A(x)$ is a biased estimator for $\theta(1 - \theta)$, we can simply correct the bias by scaling.
$$R(x) := \frac{n}{n - 1} A(x) = \frac1{n - 1} x \left( 1 - \frac{x}n \right)$$
is the desired random variable such that $E_{\theta}[R] = \frac{n}{n-1} E_{\theta}[ A ] = \theta( 1 - \theta)$ as requested.